# upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.3, now I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.2 as some software's which I need for my academic purpose can't be installed in this version. I have a problem upgrading through the GUI method of using the update manager as it gives 403 forbidden error. Is there exists any other way may be through the terminal......

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Ubuntu by using following commands:

1. Install update-manager-core if it is not already installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
   ```
2. If and only if upgrading from an LTS release, then edit
   /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts
3. Launch the upgrade tool:

   ```
   do-release-upgrade
   ```
4. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: For More Detailed information Read This: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_to_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS

Answer (score 0):

Run this from your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

After Install, Launch the update manager and Click the Check button to check for new updates. after you can upgrade to new version

[image]